# Google Play Store crashes on Amlogic Android TV

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, google-apps, android-tv

I have install Google Play Store (via flashing a GApps package through custom recovery) in an Amlogic Android TV device but after 2-3 reboots it keeps crashing.

Here are logs from `adb logcat`:

```
I/ActivityManager(  494): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity} from pid 2306
I/ActivityManager(  494): start package name is com.android.vending, class name is com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity, error code is 0
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.app.Activity.finishAfterTransition, referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 104: Landroid/app/Activity;.finishAfterTransition ()V
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0012
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 9350: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 9354: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/play/drawer/PlayDrawerLayout$1; interface 1305 'Landroid/view/View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;'
W/dalvikvm( 2306): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/play/drawer/PlayDrawerLayout$1;' failed
E/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find class 'com.google.android.play.drawer.PlayDrawerLayout$1', referenced from method com.google.android.play.drawer.PlayDrawerLayout.onFinishInflate
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 6664 (Lcom/google/android/play/drawer/PlayDrawerLayout$1;) in Lcom/google/android/play/drawer/PlayDrawerLayout;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0030
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/play/drawer/PlayDrawerLayout$1; interface 1305 'Landroid/view/View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;'
W/dalvikvm( 2306): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/play/drawer/PlayDrawerLayout$1;' failed
D/dalvikvm( 2306): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x94c8 at 0x32 in Lcom/google/android/play/drawer/PlayDrawerLayout;.onFinishInflate
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/WindowInsets;)
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.WindowInsets.getSystemWindowInsetLeft, referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.layout.InsetsFrameLayout.onApplyWindowInsets
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9371: Landroid/view/WindowInsets;.getSystemWindowInsetLeft ()I
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0020
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.View.dispatchApplyWindowInsets, referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.layout.InsetsFrameLayout.onApplyWindowInsets
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8973: Landroid/view/View;.dispatchApplyWindowInsets (Landroid/view/WindowInsets;)Landroid/view/WindowInsets;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0071
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.WindowInsets.consumeSystemWindowInsets, referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.layout.InsetsFrameLayout.onApplyWindowInsets
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9369: Landroid/view/WindowInsets;.consumeSystemWindowInsets ()Landroid/view/WindowInsets;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x007b
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>, referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.layout.SpacerHeightAwareFrameLayout.<init>
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 9808: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;II)V
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
D/TextLayoutCache( 2306): Using debug level = 0 - Debug Enabled = 0
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.content.Context.getColor, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 413: Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 417: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
D/dalvikvm( 2306): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 686K, 24% free 7774K/10188K, paused 45ms, total 45ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 2306): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.884MB for 281896-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 2306): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 24% free 8047K/10464K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal, referenced from method com.google.android.play.search.PlaySearch.onActionViewExpanded
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve static method 9155: Landroid/view/ViewAnimationUtils;.createCircularReveal (Landroid/view/View;IIFF)Landroid/animation/Animator;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x002d
E/HAL     ( 2642): load: module=/system/lib/hw/keystore.amlogic.so
E/HAL     ( 2642): dlopen failed: could not load library "libamlkeymaster.so" needed by "keystore.amlogic.so"; caused by library "libamlkeymaster.so" not found
E/keystore( 2642): could not find any keystore module
E/keystore( 2642): keystore keymaster could not be initialized; exiting
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal, referenced from method com.google.android.play.search.PlaySearchToolbar$2.onModeChanged
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve static method 9155: Landroid/view/ViewAnimationUtils;.createCircularReveal (Landroid/view/View;IIFF)Landroid/animation/Animator;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0055
E/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.layout.actionbar.ActionBarHelper.syncState
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 30 (Landroid/app/ActivityManager$TaskDescription;) in Lcom/google/android/finsky/layout/actionbar/ActionBarHelper;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x00e4
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.Window.setStatusBarColor, referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.layout.actionbar.ActionBarHelper.syncState
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9368: Landroid/view/Window;.setStatusBarColor (I)V
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x01b8
D/dalvikvm( 2306): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x009b at 0xfa in Lcom/google/android/finsky/layout/actionbar/ActionBarHelper;.syncState
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] SelfUpdateScheduler.checkForSelfUpdate: Skipping DFE self-update. Local Version [80430500] >= Server Version [-1]
D/dalvikvm(  871): GC_CONCURRENT freed 643K, 23% free 2886K/3708K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 23ms
V/GLSActivity(  871): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
V/GLSActivity(  871): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
V/GLSActivity(  871): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
V/GLSActivity(  871): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
D/libEGL  ( 2306): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
D/OpenGLRenderer( 2306): Enabling debug mode 0
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.widget.ImageView.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method com.google.android.play.image.FifeImageView.drawableHotspotChanged
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9894: Landroid/widget/ImageView;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
D/dalvikvm( 2306): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 345K, 21% free 8331K/10464K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Failed write_ctrl(u 55) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Untagging socket 55 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 2306): untagSocket(55) failed with errno -22
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] UpdateWidgetsReceiver.onReceive: Updated 0 MarketWidgetProvider widgets (com.google.android.finsky.action.TOC_SET)
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] UpdateWidgetsReceiver.onReceive: Updated 0 RecommendedWidgetProvider widgets (com.google.android.finsky.action.TOC_SET)
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] UpdateWidgetsReceiver.onReceive: Updated 0 NowPlayingWidgetProvider widgets (com.google.android.finsky.action.TOC_SET)
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 668: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 670: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] BaseWidgetProvider.onReceive: Received ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE, updating 0 widgets.
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] InstallerImpl.kick: Installer kick - starting com.google.android.gms
I/ActivityManager(  494): Displayed com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity: +664ms (total +734ms)
W/Settings( 2306): Setting download_manager_max_bytes_over_mobile has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] GaiaRecoveryHelper.prefetchAndCacheGaiaAuthRecoveryIntent: Skipping fetching recovery intent -- gaia recovery disabled
W/dalvikvm( 2306): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3; (1239)
W/dalvikvm( 2306): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3;' failed
E/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$3', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.configureTransitions
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 410 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/BackStackRecord;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x01a4
V/GLSActivity(  871): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
V/GLSActivity(  871): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.View.getTransitionName, referenced from method android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.setBackNameOverrides
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9032: Landroid/view/View;.getTransitionName ()Ljava/lang/String;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0020
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.View.getTransitionName, referenced from method android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.setNameOverrides
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9032: Landroid/view/View;.getTransitionName ()Ljava/lang/String;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0013
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.View.getTransitionName, referenced from method android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.addSharedElement
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9032: Landroid/view/View;.getTransitionName ()Ljava/lang/String;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
W/dalvikvm( 2306): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3; (1239)
W/dalvikvm( 2306): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3;' failed
D/dalvikvm( 2306): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0890 at 0x1a6 in Landroid/support/v4/app/BackStackRecord;.configureTransitions
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] MainActivity.onReady: Optimistically fetching billing countries.
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] BaseWidgetProvider.onReceive: Received ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE, updating 0 widgets.
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.z, referenced from method com.google.android.play.headerlist.PlayHeaderListLayout.setHeaderShadowVisible
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9321: Landroid/view/ViewPropertyAnimator;.z (F)Landroid/view/ViewPropertyAnimator;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0037
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method com.google.android.play.headerlist.PlayHeaderStatusBarUnderlay.setOutlineProvider, referenced from method com.google.android.play.headerlist.PlayHeaderListLayout.configure
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 38489: Lcom/google/android/play/headerlist/PlayHeaderStatusBarUnderlay;.setOutlineProvider (Landroid/view/ViewOutlineProvider;)V
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x01d5
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/WindowInsets;)
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.WindowInsets.getSystemWindowInsetTop, referenced from method com.google.android.play.headerlist.PlayHeaderListLayout.onApplyWindowInsets
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9373: Landroid/view/WindowInsets;.getSystemWindowInsetTop ()I
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] BaseWidgetProvider.onReceive: Received ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE, updating 0 widgets.
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Failed write_ctrl(u 62) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Untagging socket 62 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 2306): untagSocket(62) failed with errno -22
V/GLSActivity(  871): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
V/GLSActivity(  871): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Failed write_ctrl(u 55) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Untagging socket 55 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 2306): untagSocket(55) failed with errno -22
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] DownloadImpl.setState: Duplicate state set for 'com.google.android.gms' (0). Already in that state
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.add: Download com.google.android.gms added to DownloadQueue
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] DownloadImpl.setState: com.google.android.gms from 0 to 1.
I/installd(  136): free_cache(22795155) avail 5437329408
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] StartNextDownloadRunnable.run: Download com.google.android.gms starting
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Failed write_ctrl(u 62) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Untagging socket 62 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 2306): untagSocket(62) failed with errno -22
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [152] DownloadQueueImpl$7.run: Enqueued com.google.android.gms as content://downloads/my_downloads/3
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] DownloadImpl.setState: com.google.android.gms from 1 to 2.
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.onStart: com.google.android.gms: onStart
W/dalvikvm( 2306): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/finsky/layout/ControlsContainerBackgroundCoordinator$2; (1325)
W/dalvikvm( 2306): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/finsky/layout/ControlsContainerBackgroundCoordinator$2;' failed
E/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find class 'com.google.android.finsky.layout.ControlsContainerBackgroundCoordinator$2', referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.layout.FinskyTabStrip.onAttachedToWindow
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3013 (Lcom/google/android/finsky/layout/ControlsContainerBackgroundCoordinator$2;) in Lcom/google/android/finsky/layout/FinskyTabStrip;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x006b
W/dalvikvm( 2306): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/finsky/layout/ControlsContainerBackgroundCoordinator$2; (1325)
W/dalvikvm( 2306): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/finsky/layout/ControlsContainerBackgroundCoordinator$2;' failed
D/dalvikvm( 2306): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x502e at 0x6d in Lcom/google/android/finsky/layout/FinskyTabStrip;.onAttachedToWindow
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve static field 4997 (BACKGROUND) in Landroid/view/ViewOutlineProvider;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000b
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateOutline, referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.layout.ControlsContainerBackgroundCoordinator.updateBackgroundHeightAndFades
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9228: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.invalidateOutline ()V
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x003a
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.z, referenced from method com.google.android.play.animation.AnimationCompat.animateZ
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9321: Landroid/view/ViewPropertyAnimator;.z (F)Landroid/view/ViewPropertyAnimator;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000c
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/graphics/Outline;)
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.graphics.Outline.setRect, referenced from method com.google.android.play.headerlist.PlayHeaderListLayout$6.getOutline
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 914: Landroid/graphics/Outline;.setRect (Landroid/graphics/Rect;)V
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method com.google.android.finsky.layout.play.PlayHighlightsBannerItemView.setElevation, referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.activities.HighlightsPagerAdapter$HighlightsTab.onCurrentBannerChanged
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 23519: Lcom/google/android/finsky/layout/play/PlayHighlightsBannerItemView;.setElevation (F)V
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x002c
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method com.google.android.finsky.layout.play.PlayHighlightsBannerItemView.setElevation, referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.activities.HighlightsPagerAdapter$HighlightsTab.onCurrentBannerChanged
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 23519: Lcom/google/android/finsky/layout/play/PlayHighlightsBannerItemView;.setElevation (F)V
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x003a
V/GLSActivity(  871): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
V/GLSActivity(  871): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>, referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.layout.ControlsContainerBackground.<init>
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 9808: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;II)V
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.view.ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal, referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.layout.ControlsContainerBackground.setBackgroundDrawable
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve static method 9155: Landroid/view/ViewAnimationUtils;.createCircularReveal (Landroid/view/View;IIFF)Landroid/animation/Animator;
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0087
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.notifyProgress: com.google.android.gms: onProgress 0/-1 Status: 190.
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method com.google.android.finsky.layout.DocImageView.setTransitionName, referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.adapters.HighlightsContentBinder.bindChild
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 20813: Lcom/google/android/finsky/layout/DocImageView;.setTransitionName (Ljava/lang/String;)V
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00ac
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.widget.RelativeLayout.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method com.google.android.play.layout.ForegroundRelativeLayout.drawableHotspotChanged
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10171: Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
I/DownloadManager(  754): Download 3 starting
W/ActivityThread(  754): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
D/dalvikvm( 2306): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1394K, 15% free 9320K/10956K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
D/dalvikvm(  754): GC_CONCURRENT freed 431K, 24% free 1724K/2244K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 13ms
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Failed write_ctrl(u 62) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Untagging socket 62 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 2306): untagSocket(62) failed with errno -22
V/GLSActivity(  871): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
V/GLSActivity(  871): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
E/RecyclerView( 2306): No adapter attached; skipping layout
D/Finsky  ( 2306): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.notifyProgress: com.google.android.gms: onProgress 0/-1 Status: 192.
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Failed write_ctrl(u 84) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Untagging socket 84 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 2306): untagSocket(84) failed with errno -22
D/dalvikvm( 2306): GC_EXPLICIT freed 350K, 11% free 10748K/11984K, paused 9ms+6ms, total 86ms
I/dalvikvm( 2306): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.layout.ForegroundLinearLayout.drawableHotspotChanged
W/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9970: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V
D/dalvikvm( 2306): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Failed write_ctrl(u 62) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Untagging socket 62 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 2306): untagSocket(62) failed with errno -22
D/dalvikvm( 2306): GC_EXPLICIT freed 168K, 10% free 10855K/11984K, paused 2ms+6ms, total 85ms
D/dalvikvm(  754): GC_CONCURRENT freed 401K, 22% free 1773K/2252K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 16ms
D/dalvikvm( 2306): GC_EXPLICIT freed 171K, 9% free 12901K/14040K, paused 2ms+6ms, total 63ms
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Failed write_ctrl(u 91) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Untagging socket 91 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 2306): untagSocket(91) failed with errno -22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Failed write_ctrl(u 95) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Untagging socket 95 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 2306): untagSocket(95) failed with errno -22
V/GLSActivity(  871): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
V/GLSActivity(  871): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Failed write_ctrl(u 95) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Untagging socket 95 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 2306): untagSocket(95) failed with errno -22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Failed write_ctrl(u 84) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Untagging socket 84 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 2306): untagSocket(84) failed with errno -22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Failed write_ctrl(u 91) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Untagging socket 91 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 2306): untagSocket(91) failed with errno -22
V/RenderScript( 2306): 0x6c7f3d28 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Failed write_ctrl(u 95) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Untagging socket 95 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 2306): untagSocket(95) failed with errno -22
D/PlayCommon( 2306): [1] BitmapLoader.access$200: http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/oWjDuhYth4eSUtoYC3LQOJnXNgu4NcF5As7CgZW07HZBpnO4Yd7_Y-wh94WSYaEQVNg=rw-w683-h448 is not cached
D/PlayCommon( 2306): [1] BitmapLoader.access$200: http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/RAgEBMk9GidYnxNMN8k8vKHi19XnGn17INA06_dVi01yUrxh-lGISyvl1lDKbifFm5ju=rw-w683-h448 is not cached
D/PlayCommon( 2306): [1] BitmapLoader.access$200: http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_2y4wyOtvwASXzNaXjJ5uSABZ3tm1XnoRMLZf0UYVvJfqjut1NE4_cMWac84F7Z0LFA=rw-w683-h448 is not cached
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Failed write_ctrl(u 62) res=-1 errno=22
I/qtaguid ( 2306): Untagging socket 62 failed errno=-22
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 2306): untagSocket(62) failed with errno -22
D/AndroidRuntime( 2306): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 2306): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41687ba8)
D/dalvikvm(  754): GC_CONCURRENT freed 278K, 17% free 1883K/2252K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 13ms
E/AndroidRuntime( 2306): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2306): Process: com.android.vending, PID: 2306
E/AndroidRuntime( 2306): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to com.google.android.finsky.layout.play.PlayHighlightsBannerItemView
E/AndroidRuntime( 2306):    at com.google.android.finsky.layout.play.PlayClusterViewContentV2.getViewForItemPosition(PlayClusterViewContentV2.java:391)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2306):    at com.google.android.finsky.layout.play.PlayHighlightsBannerView.isItemLoaded(PlayHighlightsBannerView.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2306):    at com.google.android.finsky.activities.HighlightsPagerAdapter$HighlightsTab$1.run(HighlightsPagerAdapter.java:251)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2306):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2306):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2306):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2306):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2306):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2306):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2306):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
```

Updates:

When playstore update automatically to 6.0.0 version then its crashing all time older version of playstore working fine, so I found some work around from [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48694/how-can-i-stop-google-play-from-automatically-updating) check 3rd answer.

Above workaround stops playstore to updates itself and older playstore working fine.

Similar issue you can find [here](http://www.minixforum.com/threads/google-play-store-6-0-crashes.9164/page-3)

Comment: What is your Android version? Are you using a ARM32 GApps package? Your system runs a Cortex A9 processor, which is very old and may not be properly supported by the latest Play Store versions for Android 4.4 and up.

Comment: Android 4.4.2,I'm using Amlogic s802 soc and ARM32 GApps

Comment: Searching on StackOverflow, there are errors related to Multidex related development with similar signatures. The reason being unresolved dependencies. Can you refer me to the guide you used for the procedure so that I can cross check?

Comment: I'm using this guide https://nosemaj.org/howto-build-android-kitkat-nexus-5 for adding google apps to aosp build, refer "Obtain the Google Proprietary Apps"

Comment: If you're using an Android TV device, which your chipset is meant for according to WikiPedia, a standard GApps package won't be compatible with your system, which is probably the problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm using for android TV device let me try with flashing gapps from recovery.

Comment: @RRD Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde: I didn't solve but found some workaround check in my updated question.

Answer (score 3):

In our chat, and from the comments, I can identify your problem, but a solution is currently not feasible for you.

**Problem:**

The GApps don't work because you are using GApps meant for a Nexus 5 (source: your comment's [link](https://nosemaj.org/howto-build-android-kitkat-nexus-5)), a phone, on an Android TV. I'm actually not sure how it actually installed in the first place. It shouldn't have.

GApps are heavily device-specific. There are different versions by processor architecture, which isn't the problem, as both your TV and a Nexus 5 have ARMv7l based processors.

There are also different versions by screen DPI (display density), which are not necessarily intercompatible. 1st problem source.

Also, a phone running Android Kitkat and an Android TV running Android TV Kitkat do not expose the same set of APIs to applications, especially at the native level. GApps are heavily native, as illustrated above. 2nd problem source.

Just because the Android TV does not provide many of the API dependencies for a standard Android app, your GApps, meant for a phone, crash.

**Possible solutions:**

Use an ARMv7l (ARM) GApps package specifically for Android TV. This is easier said than done in your case, because, I, even after a very thorough search, couldn't locate a single applicable Android TV-specific ARM Kitkat GApps package. I did find such packages for Lollipop and Marshmallow, though.

This leaves us with not many options. The only feasible thing would be to upgrade to Lollipop or above, which, again, is easier said than done. I do not know of any Lollipop or Marshmallow custom ROMs for your device.

Links to Android TV GApps packages (Not trusted to remain available for long as there is no official host for Android TV (Leanback launcher) specific GApps):

1. Lollipop is [here](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24052804347772987).
2. Marshmallow is [here](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24269982087021941).

If there are any more anyone can find, feel free to edit them in.

Sorry to disappoint you, but you are probably stuck with whatever market app the OEM provided you.

Comment: @Firelord, very unreliable links have been added ;) (No official host for Leanback GApps)